# Update and select count at the same time taken too much time

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql statement:

```
UPDATE student_performance_cache spc SET badges = (SELECT count(ub.mb_no) FROM user_badges ub WHERE ub.mb_no=spc.student_id)
```

I got problems where this query was taken too much time when data become larger. How I can improve this mysql statement and make it faster?

Comment: Update with a join not correlated subquery. Examine indexes. Run it thru `explain `

Comment: I got it. I just update mb_no to index...it goes faster. Is there any better ways?

Comment: If `explain` says no index (for the QUERY) is in use it could be snappy with one (considering trade-offs). Google mysql explain